# Suppose $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence such that both $\liminf x_n$ and $\limsup x_n$ are finite. Prove that ${x_n}$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

Do I need to use the fact that the sequence has two convergent subsequences equal to the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$? Unsure how to proceed using the subsequences if that is the case.

Another fact that seems valuable here is that $\liminf x_n \leq \limsup x_n$.

Comment: An unbounded sequence has $\limsup_n x_n = +\infty$ or $\liminf_n x_n = -\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Let's prove that it is bounded above, the proof for bounded below is identical $$\text{Suppose }\lim \sup x_n=M $$ then for all $\epsilon>0$, there exist $N$ such that $$ \sup_{n>N}x_n< M+\epsilon$$ It follows that $\{x_n\}$ is bounded above by $$\max\{M+\epsilon,x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_N \} $$ the maximum exist as we are taking the maximum of a finite set.